# Can I enable crossfire on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ati, gpu

**How can I enable crossfire mode on Ubuntu 14?**

Graphics: 2 x AMD Radeon HD7790. Mainboard ASUS P5KC.
OS: KUbuntu 14.04 x64.

aticonfig reports:

```
aticonfig --lscs
    Candidate Combination: 
    Master: 1:0:0 
    Slave: 4:0:0 
    CrossFire is disabled on current device
    CrossFire Diagnostics:
    CrossFire can work with P2P mapping through GART
    Dongle Capabilities: support PASSTHROUGH |INTERLINK_SW_AFR | INTERLINK_AUTO_AFR | INTERLINK_BLACKING | INTERLINK_SUPERAA
```

Answer (score 1):

i do not know your motherboard ,so 1st step is to check if you have IOMMU and if is disabled

```
lspci | grep "IOMMU"
```

if it is disabled(prefer in bios) or your motherboard do not have it,then
we need to make crossfire chain

```
aticonfig --cfa --adapter=0,1
```

and then just type

```
aticonfig --cf on --adapter=0
```

then we check crossfire status with

```
aticonfig --lscs
```

If you get message that is enabled then you can proceed to some bench to actually see benefit.

Most cards 99% still need crossfire link (bridge)... Do not forget that one to attach between cards.